# Getting Information from input file C++

Tags: c++, file

I'm pretty new to coding so I'm not entirely sure if I'm doing file extraction correct. I'm getting lldb as my output for this code. Instead of prompting the user with the words in the hangman.dat file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream sourceFile;
    sourceFile.open("hangman.dat");

    if (sourceFile.fail())
    {
        cout<<"File didn't open" ;
    }

    else
    {
        string words;
        sourceFile >> words;
        while(sourceFile>>words)
        {
            cout<<words<<endl;
        }
    }

}
```

The file hangman.dat contains the following information:

```
Fall
leaves
Thanksgiving
pumpkins
turkey
Halloween
```

Comment: _"I'm not entirely sure if I'm doing file extraction correct"_ It's done correctly, what makes you doubt?

Comment: _"I'm getting lldb as my output for this code."_ What is `lldb` actually?

Comment: You didn't ask a question. The only oddities I see in this code are: (a) you never included `<string>`, which is required for using `std::string`, and (b) you seem bent on discarding the first word in your file, as it will never be printed to the console.

Comment: @user0042 It's the LLVM debugger, the default on mac OSX (among others).

Comment: @user0042   "It's done correctly"  - only if you intend not print the first word.

Comment: Line  `sourceFile >> words;` before while loop is probably redundant. It will just throw away first line.

Comment: @Marek The first word, not the first line.

Comment: @NeilButterworth you are right. Even though in this program it will be also line as there is one word per line.

Comment: Every time the while loop is true shouldn't the code print the word from the file not 11db?

Comment: @landucci `11db` again? Nothing in your code would actually lead to that output.